# ¿Cómo puedo eliminar las líneas que aparezcan repetidas seguidas X veces?

Tags: bash, unix, awk, grep, procesamiento-de-texto

Supongamos que tengo una wordlist de 10 líneas:

```
AAAAAAA
AAAAAAA
AAAAAAA
bbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbb
ddddddddd
eeeeeeeee
ffffffff
ffffffff
ffffffff
```

¿Cómo hago para eliminar los bloques de líneas que aparecen exactamente tres veces seguidas?

Yo quiero por ejemplo hacer un `grep -v AAAAAAA file` pero solo si AAAAAAA esta repetido (digamos como ejemplo) 3 veces, tampoco me serviría `grep 'string' file` en realidad porque también quiero sacar a `ffffffff` ya que esa linea esta repetida 3 veces, pero no quiero sacar a `bbbbbbbbb` que esta repetida dos veces.

Si sale bien me deberia quedar:

```
bbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbb
ddddddddd
eeeeeeeee
```

Comment: ¿Y si sale cuatro veces?

Comment: Tiene que ser exactamente 3 o puede ser '3 o más'?

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacerlo con Awk poniendo un poco de cariño a la lógica:

- ve contando cuántas veces ha salido una línea
- cuando la línea es diferente, mira cuántas veces salió la anterior. Si fue un número diferente de 3, imprime el bloque
- finalmente, mira si el último bloque apareció tres veces o no

En código:

```
function print_n_times(times, line) {
    for (i=0; i<times; i++) print line; 
}
prev!=$0 {
    if (seen>0 && seen!=3) {print_n_times(seen, prev); prev=$0; seen=1; next}
    seen=0;
 }
 {seen++}
 {prev=$0}
END {if (seen>0 && seen!=3) print_n_times(seen, $0)}
```

Guárdalo en un fichero tipo `elimina_multiples_de_3.awk` y ejecútalo con `awk -f elimina_multiples_de_3.awk fichero`.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con lo siguiente:

Si tienes que eliminar un número de líneas **exactas**:

```
cat mi_fichero | REPETICIONES=3 perl -0777 -ne '$R=$ENV{REPETICIONES}-1;s/^(.+)\R(\1(?:\R|\z)){$R}(\1(?:\R|\z))*/defined $3?$&:""/gme;print'
```

Para cambiar las repeticiones, puedes cambiar simplemente la variable que precede al comando en perl.

Si tienes que eliminar un número de líneas **mínimo** (por ejemplo: *3 o más*):

```
cat mi_fichero | REPETICIONES=3 perl -0777 -ne '$R=$ENV{REPETICIONES}-1;s/^(.*)(\R)(?:\1(?:\R|\z)){$R,}//gm;print'
```